# Group selection problem based on the score of each element of the group

Tags: statistics, algorithms

I have encountered a problem that I collected and noted from an online source. However, I am unable to find the specific link for reference at the moment. The problem is described as follows:

A list of 500 student scores(out of 100) in a contest is given, represented as [92.77, 87.67, 83.03, 81.80, 80.24, 78.66, 78.48, 78.27, 77.98, 77.63, 77.36, 77.34, 76.37,...,68.19]. **Note**: scores are sorted in descending order.

An event is being organized for the participants, and the event organizer wishes to select students based on the n highest scores.

Please note the following:

- **The event organizers are selecting students solely based on their scores.**
- **The selection criteria do not depend on a student's ability to pay for the event, the event's capacity, or any other factors.**

Now, the question is: In how many ways can the event organizer select students based on the highest score? Do they need to choose the first 50% of the students, the first 40%, or are there other methods of selection? What are the available methods or statistical tools that can help in choosing the students?

I tried using the median, Took all scores present on the left side of the median value. But, in the end, it does not make any sense.

Comment: why not take the the first n?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that first. But, how would I decide what would be the n value and depending on which method? We may take the first 50 students or 20 students but how would I decide that?

Comment: " the event organizer wishes to select students based on the n highest scores"